# Detecting the Call End Time and Status of a Twilio Incoming Call When Caller Suddenly Hangs Up

Tags: post, twilio, webhooks

I have a Twilio number which accepts incoming phone calls. If the caller hangs up all of a sudden, how do I determine in my application the end time of the call? And how do I determine the status of the call at that point? I have a webhook configured for Twilio to make POST calls to. When a caller suddenly hangs up, can I have Twilio make a POST call to this webhook and send the call end time and status as parameters in the POST? Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you [setup the webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application) already, you will receive a "completed" event when the call is ended that will include a Timestamp. The full list of parameters returned to your webhook is shown on the [StatusCallBack Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallbackevent) page of the Twilio Docs. The Timestamp is the time the call ended. If you want to determine if the caller or the callee hung-up you will need to use a [Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-resource).

> CallStatus - "completed" will trigger when the call ended normally.
>
> Timestamp - The timestamp when the event fired, given as UTC in RFC 2822 format.

The available [CallStatus values are shown in this table](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values).

Comment: I tried accessing Timestamp as a POST variable when the CallStatus changed to "in-progress" but it didn't exist. It seems it is not being sent. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How are you receiving the webhook? Are you using Ngrok? Are the other parameters like Call Sid and Account Sid showing?

Comment: The webhook URL represents a Sanic Python function that extracts the values of POST parameters from the request object. Yes, values for the CallSid and AccountSid parameters are available but Timestamp isn't.

Comment: Can you check the Twilio logs? It should show that when your webhook is called it is sent a Timestamp in this format: "Sun, 22 Oct 2023 15:41:05 +0000"